# Let $f$ be a continuous function on $\Bbb R$ satisfying $f(f(f(x)))=x ;\ \forall x \in \Bbb R$. Then is $f$ the identity function?

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

I don't know what the answer is but I tried to get some information from the hypothesis and have reached till the result that $f$ is an homeomorphism.

This is because $f$ is bijective and continuous as well as it's inverse is also continuous because $f \circ f=f^{-1}$ and composition of continuous functions is continuous.

What should be my next step? or this is not the way to reach the answer?

Comment: This is a [cyclic function](https://www.artofproblemsolving.com/wiki/index.php/Functional_equation#Cyclic_Functions) of order $3$.

Comment: The requirement that this be a function of one variable is important: In 2D, one has for instance the map $f(x,y)=(-\frac{1}{2}x-\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}y,\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}x-\frac{1}{2}y)$ which satisfies the required condition but only corresponds to the identity at $f(0)=0$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following proof is overkill (assuming it's valid---correct me if I'm wrong), but I like Sharkovsky's theorem so here it is.

Proof: Assume $f(x_0)\neq x_0$ for some $x_0\in\Bbb R$. This, along with the condition that $(f\circ f\circ f)(x_0)=x_0$, means that $x_0$ is a periodic point of least period 3. We then appeal to [Sharkovsky's theorem](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SharkovskysTheorem.html) in dynamical systems, which has the following implication: "If a continuous real function has a periodic point with least period 3, then there is a periodic point of least period $n$ for every integer $n$." In particular, there should be a periodic point of least period 5. But every point is 3-periodic, so we have a contradiction and conclude that $f(x)=x$ everywhere. $\blacksquare$

Comment: @RossMillikan Aye. I think what I'm being careless about is the difference between assuming $f(x)$ is not the identity map _anywhere_ versus it not being the identity map _somewhere_. The contradiction I've derived only shows that it must be the identity map _somewhere_.

Comment: @RossMillikan That said, I think it can be saved as such: If $f(x)$ is not the identity map at a point $x_0$, then $x_0$ is a periodic point of least period 3 and Sharkovsky's theorem implies that periodic points of arbitrary least period exist. In particular, a periodic point of least period 5 exists. But this isn't compatible with $f(f(f(x)))=x$, so no such $x_0$ exists.

Comment: @RossMillikan I've edited the answer to incorporate the logic I stated, so if it's still flawed let me know.

Comment: Can you point me towards any source to read about Sharkovsky's theorem? I haven't encountered this theorem yet in my studies. Also in your proof can't $f(f(x_0))$ be equal to $x_0$ ? I mean what if $f(f(x_0))=x_0$? In that case $x_0$ will be periodic point with period 2 right?

Comment: I meant that least period will be 2 in that case.

Comment: @VikrantDesai The Mathworld page contains some sources; I think I learned about it from the book by Devanay. As for the point re: period 2 points: You already have by assumption $f(f(f(x_0)))=x_0,$ so if $f(f(x_0))=x_0$ as well you've got $f(x_0)=x_0$. But I should've included that explicitly.

Comment: That's it then. I learnt new things also due to this answer. :) The ordering of positive integers proposed by Sharkovsky for his theorem is peculiar.

Answer (score 1):

I think that the more than $2$ iterations of $f(...f(f(x))..) = x$ has no solution for a continuous function $f(x)$. Here is my proof:

Let $f:\mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ such that $f^n=I$ for some $n>2$, and $f^k\neq I$ for any $k<n$. ($I$ is the identity function $I(x)=x$.)
We know that $f$ is continuous and injective (if $f(a)=f(b$), then $a=f^n(a)=f^n(b)=b$), so it must be strictly monotonic.
Suppose $f$ is increasing. Since $f$ isn't the identity, there is some $x$ with $f(x)\neq x$.
Suppose $f(x)>x$. Since $f$ is increasing, $x<f(x)<f(f(x))<f(f(f(x)))<....$ By induction, $x<f^n(x)$.
Suppose $f(x)<x$. Then $x>f(x)>f(f(x))>....$ By a similar argument, $x>f^n(x)..$
In neither case could $f^n(x)=x$. Thus $f$ must not be increasing. This even shows that $n=2$ doesn't work; i.e. if $f$ is increasing, $f^2\neq I$.

Now suppose $f$ is strictly decreasing. $f^2$ is increasing, so the above shows that $g=f^2$ must not satisfy $g^n=I$ for any $n>1$. If $g^1=I$, then $f^2=I$, which we assumed was false. Hence no power of $f^2$ is the identity. But $f^n=I$, so $(f^2)n=f^{2n}=(fn)^2=I.$ This is impossible, so $f$ must not be decreasing.
Since $f$ must be monotonic, and not increasing or decreasing, $f$ can't exist.

Comment: Regarding your first claim, ouldn't $f(x)=-x$ be a solution for $f(f(f(f(x))))=x$ with four iterations? In the decreasing case, I would argue that $f^3$ is also decreasing, hence can not be equal to $I$.

Answer (score 1):

Follow the facts and have the answer.

1. Since $f\circ f\circ f=x\implies f$ is injective.
2. $f$ is either increasing or decreasing since it is continuous and injective.
3. Claim: $f$ is increasing .If not then $f\circ f$ is increasing and then $f\circ f\circ f=x$ is decreasing false.
4. If $f(x_0)\neq x_0\implies f(x_0)<x_0 $ or $f(x_0)>x_0$.
5. WLOG ,let $f(x_0)>x_0\implies f(f(x_0))>x_0(\text {by}(3))\implies f(f(f(x_0)))>x_0\implies x_0>x_0$ false